# How to change javascript object key value order bydefault

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

## **

## I am try to getting expected output like this in javascript but every time when i print render with all key and value in sorted form so how i can get this expected output in javascript.**

```
let obj1 =  {"business": false, "economy": true, "first": false, "premium": true}
```

```
expected output = { "economy": true, "premium": true,"business": false, "first": false}
```

```
expected output = { "economy": true, "premium": true,"business": false, "first": false}
```

Comment: Input 
let obj1 =  {"business": false, "economy": true, "first": false, "premium": true}

Expected output should be 
expected output = { "economy": true, "premium": true,"business": false, "first": false}

Comment: Duplicate of [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Answer (score -1):

Objects do not have a strict iteration order, unlike arrays. Just use arrays

```
let obj1 = {"business": false, "economy": true, "first": false, "premium": true}

const obj1Order = ["economy", "premium","business", "first"]

for(let key of obj1Order){
  console.log(obj1[key])
}
```

Or

```
let obj1 = [{"business": false}, {"economy": true}, {"first": false}, {"premium": true}]

for(let element of obj1){
  console.log(element)
}
```

Comment: Objects have a strict iteration order since 2015. See the duplicate.